# Visibile/collapsed button on a grid view in C# WP8 Development

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Guyes I am new in windows phone 8 dev.
I have issue to control Grid view visibilty and visibilty on that buttons which are located on that grid..
Here is my xaml view snapshot..

http://www.4shared.com/photo/Hu1FVCdn/wp8.html

here is my Xaml view...I have a grid view at left side and buttons on it.(1,2,3,4,5)...Visibilty of these buttons is collapsed...when trade button is clicked I I like to all the buttons visible..But There are 2,3 errors shows in my screen..

Here is My xaml.cs code..

```
  public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    private void Grid_View_Btn_1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

       // a.Visible = !a.Visible;
         a.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Also possible to Collapse (hide). 
      b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Also possible to Collapse (hide).
      c.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Also possible to Collapse (hide).
       d.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Also possible to Collapse (hide).
      e.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Also possible to Collapse (hide).

        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    }
```

Here is my xaml code..

```
     <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="618" Margin="6,147,0,0" Width="112" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pannel.png"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Button x:Name="a" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-7,-11,-11,563" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="130" RenderTransformOrigin="0.636,0.638" Height="66" BorderThickness="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pannel_btn_unselected.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="b" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-7,0,-11,519" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="130" RenderTransformOrigin="0.636,0.638" Height="66" BorderThickness="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pannel_btn_unselected.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="c" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-7,0,-11,475" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="130" RenderTransformOrigin="0.636,0.638" Height="66" BorderThickness="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pannel_btn_unselected.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="d" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-7,0,-11,431" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="130" RenderTransformOrigin="0.636,0.638" Height="66" BorderThickness="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pannel_btn_unselected.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="e" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-7,0,-11,387" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="130" RenderTransformOrigin="0.636,0.638" Height="66" BorderThickness="0" d:IsHidden="True">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pannel_btn_unselected.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

The error which comes out is this   **"Error: 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Visibility' and no extension method 'Visibility' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

Kindly help me out for my problem...
I just wanna get visibility of that buttons after clicking Trade button...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event handler Grid_View_Btn_1_Click has a parameter "e". When referencing "e", the handler will use the parameter "e", not the control "e". Rename the handlers parameter to "e2" or similar.

Comment: Or even better, call your buttons something other than a - e